# Como faço para substituir Virgula por Ponto no VBA

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Como faço para substituir uma virgula por um ponto usando VBA?

A seguinte macro não funciona:

```
Range("F2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, 
    SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode formatar a coluna inteira no Excel como número com divisor decimal ".", manualmente no Excel e sem VBA. Mas se desejar usar o VBA veja a função [Format](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications)

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema é bem simples: você está misturando alhos com bugalhos. Você está buscando uma `string` (",") dentro de uma célula que contém um valor não-string.

Eu apostaria alto que os preços na coluna F estão formatados como número. Resultado: o Excel busca a string ",", não encontra nenhuma para substituir e não retorna erro nem faz qualquer alteração na planilha.

Para seu código funcionar sem qualquer alteração, basta transformar os valores em strings (abra a célula e insira uma aspa simples `'` no começo, antes do valor; não precisa de espaço. Ou seja: em vez de `2,39`, coloque `'2,39`, e assim por diante. *Voilà*!

Ou seja, a macro *funciona*; só não faz o que você quer.

Se você quiser apenas mudar o formato para que os decimais sejam marcados por ponto e as casas dos milhares sejam marcadas por vírgula, você tem que mudar a forma de marcação dos decimais, e não os valores contidos.

Eu só consigo imaginar dois motivos para fazer isso: uma apresentação internacional ou usar uma planilha do google.

Se você precisa colar numa planilha do Google, eu acho que essa conversão já é feita automaticamente. Para uma apresentação internacional, basta pesquisar como mudar a marcação de decimais e milhares no Excel -- mas é recomendável mexer nisso com MUITO cuidado, porque você pode gerar problemas de compatibilidade em outros computadores, e tanto você quanto outros usuários (caso o computador seja utilizado por outras pessoas) podem terminar criando confusões em valores que atingem a ordem de milhares de reais!

Answer (score 0):

algo deste género ?

```
Sub teste()
 Dim valor_range As Range
    
     For Each valor_range In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z500")
        valor_range.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", MatchCase:=True
     Next
     
End Sub
```

No range pretendido procura por "," e substitui por "."